# Strassen's Matrix Multiplication Example Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

How to multiply two matrices using strassen's matrix multiplication.I have only learned the theory part but i cannot find any examples on the net.

Could some one explain with two 2X2 Matrices.

Comment: There is nothing to explain in the $2\times 2$ case, as the theory is just an explicit formula for the entries of the multiplied matrix, with the efficiency gain coming from the fact that Strassen found a way to do this computation with only 7 multiplications (instead of the 8 required for the standard algorithm).  You should try to work an example in the $4\times 4 case$ instead.  The trick is that you view a $4\times 4$ matrix as a $2\times 2$ block of $2\times 2$ matrices, apply the exact same formulas, taking care that the order of multiplication matters.

Comment: @Aaron Can you explain how the order of multiplication works

Comment: By that I just meant that matrix multiplication is not commutative.  From the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm), we have formulas like $M_3:=A_{1,1}(B_{1,2}-B_{2,2})$, and while these are all scalar quantities in the $2\times 2$ case, they become matrices in higher cases.  Because of this, you have to be careful to NOT use $(B_{1,2}-B_{2,2})A_{1,1}$ because it gives a different answer when the quantities involved are not scalar.